# SmtpClient.Dispose throws System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, smtpclient

My code sends e-mails like this:

```
    private void DispatchMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
```

The MailMessage instances are very simple with a HTML body and no attachments.

The configuration of the SmtpClient is in web.config like this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="yourmail@gmail.com">
            <network host="mailprovider.org" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="username@host" password="secret" />
       </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Whenever the method DispatchMail is called, the mail is actually sent to the recipient, however I get an exception in the implicitly called SmtpClient.Dispose method.

> Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>       at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>       at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>       at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpPooledStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>       at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
>       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
>       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.ForceCleanup()
>       at System.Net.ConnectionPoolManager.CleanupConnectionPool(ServicePoint servicePoint, String groupName)
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Dispose()
>       at QueuedMailDispatcherService.DispatchMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
>
> Inner exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Is this a bug in the .NET Framework 4.5.2 or am I mismanaging the life-cycle of the SMTP client?

The SMTP server in question responds as "Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service".

### Update

First I dismissed this problem since it only happened on my machine, but then it happened on the production machine running same code but with release configuration.

Since this error happens intermittently I have decided to modify the method to use a two-level exception handling strategy where any exception occurring when Dispose is called is ignored.

When I was able to catch this error and step through the framework source it seemed like the offset parameter was corrupted (it was several MB higher than the buffer.Length) somewhere between System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read and System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive. However further inspection of the source does not imply that the offset would be changed. In fact System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader sets offset to 5 higher up in the call stack. This leads me to believe that one of the following things happened:

- The debugged machine level code was not matching the source I stepped through in Visual Studio
- Some kind of memory corruption (however the problem has persisted through one reboot and on two different machines both in debug and release configuration)
- I was actually debugging two different threads without realizing it
- There is some kind of difficult rare race condition going on
- There is some kind of optimization going wrong, maybe in combination with the race condition
- The SMTP server implementation or the network transmission is not reliable during SMTP Quit, however it is a well known SMTP server software and I cannot see why this problem would be intermittent also it does not explain the out of bound offset value.

Comment: Given that the Inerr Exception states `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` suggests that this is more likely a problem connecting to the SMTP server. I'd double check the settings to make sure they're correct.

Comment: are you using a gmail account by anychance?

Comment: I believe the connection is fine, the connection is setup and the message is after all being sent. It seems like the mail server is disconnecting the client while the call to Dispose is being processed, however this should be valid as far as I know.

Comment: This is a medium sized hosted mail provider, not gmail.

Comment: It looks like the server is committing a protocol violation.  This dies when .NET sends the QUIT command.  The server is supposed to acknowledge it with a 221 response.  But instead it instantly terminated the connection without sending a response.  Bug report to the server owner is recommended, meanwhile you'll have to wrap the Dispose() call in try/catch.

Comment: I am getting this same error intermittently using Microsoft Office 365. Quite annoying...

Answer (score -1):

Try the below sample:

```
using System.Net.Mail;


private void DispatchMail(string to)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = "subject",
        From = new MailAddress(@"sender email", @"sender name")
    };
    mail.To.Add(to);
    mail.Body = "your message body";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient(@"smtp mail server address");
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);

    mail.Dispose();
    smtp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Also, you can handle the `SendCompletedCallBack` by following this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Same error occurs with this example, on smtp.Dispose in this case.

Comment: So, it seems the server has an issue, so I recommend doing the same with Gmail or Hotmail and test.

Comment: Yes, the problem is likely some kind of compatibility issue with the hosting provider. It seems like the server disconnects the socket and when Dispose is called it throws an exception when there is no working socket to the server.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
           var fromAddress = new MailAddress("fromAddress", "My Name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("gtoAddress ", "Mr Test");
            const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
            string subject = "hello";
            string body = "how are you doing?";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {

                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
                Timeout = 20000
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);

            }
```

and enable less secure apps on your Gmail account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)